# How to put a Sizedbox or spacing after every quote Mapping in thus flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart

When i run this code, i get a thickly arranged Quotes.. i need spacing after every quotes.. How can i do that without entering Sizedbox manually or hard coding between every Text widget?

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'List of Data',
  home: QuoteList()
));

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteListState createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {
  List<Widget> quotes =[
    Text('We are what we believe we are!'),
    Text('Those who have courage and faith shall never perish in misery'),
    Text('It takes courage to grow up and become who you really are')
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Amazing Quotes'),centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      ),
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:quotes.map((quote)=> (quote)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try SizeBox() after the Text widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(title: 'List of Data', home: QuoteList()),
    );

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteListState createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {
  List<Widget> quotes = [
    QuoteText('We are what we believe we are!'),
    QuoteText('Those who have courage and faith shall never perish in misery'),
    QuoteText('It takes courage to grow up and become who you really are')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Amazing Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: quotes.map((quote) => (quote)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuoteText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String quote;

  const QuoteText(this.quote, {Key key})
      : assert(quote != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        quote,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mapping to list and using column, you can do it using `ListView`

**A complete example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  List<Widget> quotes = [
    Text('We are what we believe we are!'),
    Text('Those who have courage and faith shall never perish in misery'),
    Text('It takes courage to grow up and become who you really are')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Amazing Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: quotes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => quotes[i],
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```